# How to customize Resharper's "code clean up" to change the documentation header rules in C#

Tags: c#, resharper, code-cleanup

I would like to use code clean up to automatically create the documentation headers in the following way:

```
/// <summary>
/// **Some summary.**
/// </summary>
/// <param name="myParam">**The param.**</param>
/// <typeparam name="TService">**The type.**</typeparam>
/// <returns>**Whatever.**</returns>
TService Do<TService>(int myParam)
```

This is, summary has multiple lines but the rest of the fields use a single line. Currently my default resharper settings always use multiple lines.

What is the set of rules that control this behavior in Resharper "code clean up"? Is it possible?

Comment: I understand it can be easy to forget, but please use code formatting when you post.

Comment: Thanks, Mike, I was actually doing it when you beat me to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Resharper's code cleanup won't do this, but you can use [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx). It can even write correct comments for a lot of common methods (constructors, event handlers, properties, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I won't create XML doc comments, only reformat them.

It *will* update file header though...